# Set specified locale in wicket where default(for user) are not aviable

Tags: wicket, locale

I have properties files oriented for specific language only (page_ru_RU.prop and page_en_GB.prop). Where on this page came user with locale en US - he got exception, because no proper locale found.
Can i in this way make somwhere check to manual set locale if user dont have any aviable locale without make default locale (page.prop)
If I am not clear about, please tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create a properties file with just the language only, it will be used for all variants: so instead of `page_en_GB.properties`, you can have a `page_en.properties`, which will be used for all en_* sublocales.

You can also have a plain `page.peroperties`, which will be used for everyone who doesn't fit into a more specific category.

**Update:** Take two, how to take control of `Locale` selection completely.

Locale in Wicket  is stored in the `Session` object, it can be manipulated using the `getLocale()` and `setLocale()` method. This alone might give you a solution, but you can also intercept calls to these methods to override locale selection automaticlly.

```
//this is your application class
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

  @Override      
  public Session newSession( Request req, Response res ) {
    return new MySession( req )
  }
}

//this is your session class
public class MySession extends WebSession {
  public MySession( Request req ) {
    super( req );
  }

  @Override
  public void setLocale( Locale locale ) {
    // your locale substitution code goes here, for example:
    if( locale.getLanguage().equals( "en" ) ) {
      super.setLocale( new Locale( "en", "GB" ) );
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the sort of thing you're after?

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this isnt what i want. I want to have only language oriented(o_O) locales (page_en_GB, not page_en or page) and if user come with locale that i dont have to use some one from my locale that i have. Can i somehow do exactly this.

Comment: @user600115 Okay, I'm going to try to find a solution for that then.

Comment: What if you renamed your page_en_GB to page (assuming you want GB to be the fallback) and then provide page_xx_YY files for those that you specifically support? A user with a locale that is not supported will simply fall back to 'page' which is actually en/GB